# Magento 2: After adding products to cart programmatically, cart is not refreshing until reloading page

Tags: magento2, module, cart, extensions, addtocart

Hello Magento 2 Friends.

I have an ajax call to an controller, which adds some new products to the cart programmatically. This works fine, but the problem is that **the cart and the mini cart are only refreshed after reloading page**. Is there any code I can add, so I don't need to reload the page?

This is my ajax call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: myurl,
  data: {
    productIds: response._productId,
    amounts: response._amount,
  },
  success: function (data){
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(data, data1){
    console.log(data);
  },
});
```

Controller.php

```
<?php

namespace MassiveArt\ShoppingCart\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

class Index extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var FormKey
     */
    protected $formKey;

    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var Cart
     */
    protected $cart;

    /**
     * @var Product
     */
    protected $product;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
     * @param FormKey $formKey
     * @param Cart $cart
     * @param Product $product
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        FormKey $formKey,
        Cart $cart,
        Product $product
    ) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->product = $product;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        try {

            // Set result data and pass back
            $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();

            if(!$this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId()) {
                $result->setData(['error' => __('Invalid session ID')]);
            }



            // Get parameters
            $productIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('productIds');
            $amounts = $this->getRequest()->getParam('amounts');

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($productIds); $i++) {// Load product by ID
                $product = $this->product->load($productIds[$i]);
                // New product params
                $params = array(
                    'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                    'product' => $productIds[$i],
                    'qty'   => $amounts[$i],
                );


                // Save Product
                $product->save();

                // Add product to cart
                $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
            }

            //Save cart
            $this->cart->save();

            $result->setData(['message' => __("Products added succesfully")]);

            return $result;
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            $result->setData(['error' => __($e->getMessage())]);
            return $result;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you might know mini cart renders from local storage. So after performing ajax request you need to reload mini cart to update qty. For that you need to create section.xml file.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
<action name="modulename/controler/addProduc">
    <section name="cart"/>
</action>
```

If you don't have controller still you can reload cart from your template file by using below code.

```
require([
           'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
        ], function (customerData) {
            var sections = ['cart'];
            customerData.invalidate(sections);
            customerData.reload(sections, true);
        });
```

Fore more you can read this. https://webkul.com/blog/update-mini-cart-magento2/

Comment: Thanks for your help, the minicart gets refreshed now, but the main cart is still not refreshing. Any ideas?

Comment: Where you are performing ajax request ? I mean which page at frontend.

Comment: I perform the ajax Request directly in the cart view frontend. Could this be the problem?

Comment: You mean when cart page opens up your ajax will perform ?

Comment: No my ajax performs when you click a button in the cart page

Comment: Can you paste controller in question so that I can take a look.

Comment: Yeah sure, just a moment. Edited my question

Comment: I added my Controller now

Comment: Ah okay so when your ajax request performs product added, but it shows up after reload Right ? If you take a look it wont update directly. You must have to reload page to refresh right side section. In stead a button you can create pop-up in that you can show your product and then reload page. Its just basic idea. But update whole cart page is not good practice.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. Yes after reload everything works. I will try some other stuff.